# Codeigniter form_validation create custom rule/filter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Codeigniters form_validation is great, however I need a custom filter that is specifically

> alpha space dash and apostrophe/single quote

but.. they don't have that specifically in there existing set, so I am wondering how could I go about creating my own rule/filter and adding it to form_validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Callbac ks are your friend](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

You'll just just a custom callback - and put a regex in there that does whatever rule you want.

Comment: You don't have to use a callback function either. You can also extend the form validation class (create a MY_form_validation) and write your own custom functions that can be used whenever your load the form validation. I find that to be much more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation for CodeIgniter's form validation tool.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules