# How do I create a new validation rule for messages? (Codeigniter)

Tags: regex, codeigniter

I couldn't find an existing rule that handled exactly what I required.

How do I create a new [rule refrence](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) in [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) so it:

Returns FALSE if the form element contains anything other than alpha-numeric characters, underscores, dashes, **spaces** or **fullstops** (periods).

The rule is intended to be used for validating messages for a contact form.

Comment: Be careful with this -- if you're validating a visitor's message in a contact form, that regex will fail if they use a comma, colon, exclamation point, etc. All normally perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need a custom callback - and put a regex in there that does whatever rule you want. which you can modify according to your needs.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'callback_description_check');

public function direction_check($str)
{
    return strip_tags($text, '<p><a>'); 
}
```

Refer:-
[Codeigniter form_validation create custom rule/filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840382/codeigniter-form-validation-create-custom-rule-filter)

Comment: The name of the function is direction_check and the name of the rule is description_check.... Is that correct?